# Finding where in a String validation failed

Tags: java, regex, validation, exception

Just trying to figure out the best way to do this.

I have a few validation methods that my input String goes through:

```
public class Validator {

    private static final String VALID_INFIX_REGEX = "^[0-9(]([\\s0-9+*/()-])*[0-9)]$";

    public boolean validate(String input) {
        return (isValidInfixExpression(input) && hasBalancedParenthesis(input) && checkIfOperatorsAppearConsecutively(input));
    }

    private boolean isValidInfixExpression(String input) {

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(VALID_INFIX_REGEX);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        return matcher.matches();
    }

    private boolean hasBalancedParenthesis(String input) {

        String[] tokens = input.split("\\s");

        int unclosedParenthesis = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {

            if ("(".equals(tokens[i])) {
                unclosedParenthesis++;
            } else if (")".equals(tokens[i])) {
                unclosedParenthesis--;
            }
        }
        return (unclosedParenthesis == 0);
    }

    private boolean checkIfOperatorsAppearConsecutively(String input) {

        String[] tokens = input.split("\\s");

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if (Operator.isOperator(tokens[i])) {

                if ("(".equals(tokens[i - 1]) || ")".equals(tokens[i + 1]) || Operator.isOperator(tokens[i + 1])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

For a user I want to be able to grab where in the String it failed validation and display back to them.

Where I pass my String into validation I throw an exception if failed:

```
if (validator.validate(input)) {
    // execute
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Am I better to throw exceptions in the actual validation methods in order to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: "Am I better to throw exceptions in the actual validation" - Yes. You can also consider returning enum with string validation result instead of boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know where the validation failed you will need to return back some form of an object with the result of where it failed.

I recommend creating a new exception to do this:

```
public class InvalidInputException extends IllegalArgumentException {

    private int errorIndex;

    public InvalidInputException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public InvalidInputException(String message, int index) { 
         super("Invalid Input at index: " + index + " " + message);
         errorIndex = index;
    }

    public int getErrorIndex() { return errorIndex; }
}
```

Then you can adapt your validation methods to detected where your validations failed and include that in the exception. E.g.

```
throw new InvalidInputException("Missing closing parenthesis", 200);
```

or

```
throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid format");
```

Comment: I eventually came up with something like this myself but yours is much cleaner, thanks for your help!